# Middleware function not working properly in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using "express js", Right now i am working on "middleware function",Right now whenever i hit
"http://localhost:3000/api/example" on browser then i am getting "Router middleware executed" in console,but i have few questions

```
1) why not middleware2 executed (not getting "middleware2 executed" in console.log) ?
2) How many times we can use "next" in middleware functions ?
```

Here is my current code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Create a router instance
const router = express.Router();

// Define a middleware function specific to the router
const routerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Perform some operations on the request or response
  console.log('Router middleware executed');
  next();
};

const middleware2 = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Middleware 2 executed');
  //next();
};


router.get('/example', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from the router');
});

app.use('/api',routerMiddleware,router);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: You never use `middleware2` anywhere

Comment: *How many times we can use "next" in middleware functions?* - once per function

Comment: @Konrad if i am not wrong then "next" means ....function will redirect to "next function" (middleware2/after current function) then why not i am getting message(middleware2 executed) in my console ?

Comment: You have to use this function `app.use(middleware2)`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You defined the middleware2 function but did not call it.
> 2. You can call next() once in each function

So, next() lets you go to the next function from where the function was called.

For example in this section,

```
app.use('/api',routerMiddleware,router);
```

next() in routermiddleware directs you to the next function, router. If you also wanna run middleware2 before reaching router.

Your code should be like this,

```
app.use('/api',routerMiddleware,middleware2,router);
```

This way next() in routermiddleware will redirect you to middleware2 and next() in middleware2 will redirect you to router.

NOT: You have to call next() in middleware2 otherwise you won't reach the router.